# Font Awesome in Blade form?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, templating

I have a table in a blade template and at the end of each row I have a button that deletes that row. In order to do this, I

```
{!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs']) !!}
```

Now I want to replace the 'Delete' with an icon. How can i achieve something like

```
{!! Form::submit(<i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
, ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs']) !!}
```

Cheers

Edit1:
this is my complete code:

```
@foreach($student->language as $language)
            {{ $language->name }}

            {!! Form::open([
                    'method'=>'DELETE',
                    'url' => ['profile/language', $language->id],
                    'style' => 'display:inline'
                ]) !!}
            {!! Form::button('<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs']) !!} 
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        @endforeach
```

Comment: {!! Form::submit('<i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
, ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs']) !!} doesn't work?

Comment: No, that way I see the text '<i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>' inside the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `<button>` of the type submit instead

```
{!! Form::button('<i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => '')) !!}
```

Comment: Yes, sir!! Worked like a charm

Comment: Did not worked as I expected. Although the icon appears, now the button does not submit.
I edited my post with the entire code.

Comment: You didn't add this: array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => '')